# iOS Different ways to go from one VC to another one

Tags: ios, window, warnings, segue, hierarchy

I get a warning "Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the windows hierarchy.. " that comes and goes. Although all works to plan, I don't like warnings so I would like to better understand all the ways available to go from one VC to another.

I know 3 ways, please correct me if I am wrong.

1- I create a button in VC1 with an action. I create a segue from VC1 to VC2 with a name (here VC1ToVC2) and in my action method, I call the segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VC1ToVC2" sender:self];
```

2- I create a button in VC1 and from this button, I create a Segue directly to VC2.

3- I create a button in VC1 with an action. I make sure my VC2 has a storyboard name and then I write in my action :

```
UIViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"VC2"];
 [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My impression is that the way 3 is mostly used to "go somewhere" and then "come back" to the same place with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

like when uisng a Help for example.

What is exactly the difference between way1 and way2? I tried both and they both work.

Is one of these 3 ways more prone to cause a "Window hierarchy..." message ?

How can such a message come and go without me doing anything? It makes it difficult to track.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Difference :

1) `Seque` is `binded` with `UIObject` and need to `perform custom triggering` then `performSegueWithIdentifier` is used which `triggers seque`.

2) `Seque` is binded with `UIButton` so `triggering` is `done` and `seque performed`.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation Prince. 
Is one of them better than the other?
Which one has then the more "chances" to cause the window hierarchy problem or does it have nothing to do with it ?

Comment: it have nothing to do with window hierarchy problem its ways to show viewcontroller according requirement

Comment: Any idea why the warning "Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the windows hierarchy.. " comes and goes, Prince?

Comment: There is something on top of UIWindow like UIAlertView so u need to dismiss currently presented and then present your controller.